# Probability, Expected value, Average value

Tags: probability

From a box containing 26 different letter cubes(A through Z), you get t pull out three cubes in order, without replacement( even without putting the cubes back in between). If you pull out first letter A, then the B, then the C,spelling ABC you win 10000, otherwise you lose your wager, it costs 1$ to play. is it worth it? what is the expected value of playing this game?

I know the probability of getting ABC is 1/26*1/25*1/24, but how to calculate expected value?

Comment: The expected value is $P(Winning)*10000 + P(Losing)*(-1)$

Comment: Why multiply by (-1)?

Comment: do you mean: p (1/26*25*24)*10000+ (25/26*24/25* 23/24)* (-1)

Comment: Shardulc's answer is correct. P(Losing) = 1 - P(Winning) as you can see from Shardulc's answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you say, the probability of getting A, B, and C in that order on the first three tries is $\frac{1}{26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24}$. With this probability, you will win 10000 which is a gain of 9999 (you paid 1 at the start). With a probability of $1 - \frac{1}{26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24}$ you will lose 1, which is to say you will gain $-1$. Thus the expected value is
$$\frac{1}{26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24} \cdot 9999 + \Big(1 - \frac{1}{26 \cdot 25 \cdot 24}\Big) \cdot -1 = \frac{-14}{39} \approx -0.36$$

Comment: why multiply by (-1)?

Comment: @liza Because you will *lose* \$1 if you don't get ABC.

Comment: I get it.Thanks.

Comment: You could also compute it as $\frac{10000}{26\cdot25\cdot24} - 1$, since you pay $1$ for each game,regardless of winning or losing.

Comment: Now we have 3 different answer,1) -0.36 2) 0.84 3) and the fist answer. I got totally confused.

Comment: @Liza How three? True blue anil's and mine give the same answer, and the one in the comments on the question is slightly wrong.